# IOS custom keyboard extension make delete all button

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

Is there a method that allows me to clear all the text in a textfield in a custom keyboard extension? (I don't have access to the `UITextView` object, so setting that to `""` is not an option).

Currently, the only method I know that allows me to delete text is:

```
(textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).deleteBackward()
```

but this is only called 1 character at a time leading to performance/lag issues.